Cannot compile scss file through sass module
I need a map of initial values, so I'm using this
spacer.scss
@use "sass:map";

$initial: 4px;

$values: ();

@for $i from -5 through 12 {
  $spacers: map.sets($spacers, $i, $i * $spacer);
}

Using sass module for compiling

const result = sass.compile('./spacer.scss');


But it throws an error while compiling
  ╷
7 │   $spacers: map.sets($spacers, $i, $i * $spacer);
  │             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵


You have a typo in your scss file.
map.sets is not a map function.
use  map.set instead
@use "sass:map";

$initial: 4px;

$values: ();

@for $i from -5 through 12 {
  $spacers: map.set($spacers, $i, $i * $spacer);
}

